# Cochran-Armitage trend test: variance of the T-statistic derivation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, trend, cochran-armitage

I’m trying to figure out the math behind the formula for the variance of the T-stat in Cochran-Armitage trend test show in Wikipedia.[image]

It says that decomposition is used, however I can’t work this out. [image]

Any insights or resources would be greatly appreciated!